# FMDB block my UI

Tags: ios, json, fmdb

Fmdb in iOS, I have a task to convert 100 JSON string to my model from network and then represent them on the UITableViewCell, because I have 3 button to change the data on the UITableView , so I fmdb the data to local,  when I change the data it first check to read the local data, and then request newest data to reload UITableView and save to database.  All 3 changes have the same logic. Because 100 data to store I choose to asynchronous dispatch the for statement, then the problem is when the model inserts in to table it stuck my UI a little bit.  My table has 10+ columns , is there any possibility just because too much columns cause insert  assume too much time?

Comment: "Jason"?  Did you only hear the requirements and not see them written down?

Comment: @Droppy json data, sorry to type wrong, the insert procedure is successfully, only the procedure block my UI !

Comment: "asynchronous dispatch" to which queue?

Comment: @Justin Then you probably are not dispatching the procedure asynchronously

Comment: @Droppy global queue with 0 , 0 by default !

Comment: @simpleBob i use dispatch_async method, then I'm sure it is!

Comment: Well that sounds OK to me.  We need code to continue investigation if you want to avoid guesswork.

Comment: @Justin, but you don't do `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),...)`, do you?

Comment: @Droppy ok I will post it tomorrow morning, cause I am on the way home, just off work! Thanks , tomorrow I notice you,!

Comment: @simpleBob not on the main thread , replace inner with global_queue!

Comment: @Justin make sure you don't set the priority to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`

Comment: @simpleBob  I  use  dispatch_queue_t and then the problem none exist. and i try to use DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH is not work for me. Now i want to know since the elements in the sqlite table already have lock && unlock in the FMDB source code , so why should we need queue to solve this multi-thread problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to FMDB documentation, it's better to use `FMDatabaseQueue` for your case.

> To perform queries and updates on multiple threads, you’ll want to use FMDatabaseQueue.
>
> Using a single instance of FMDatabase from multiple threads at once is a bad idea. It has always been OK to make a FMDatabase object per thread. Just don’t share a single instance across threads, and definitely not across multiple threads at the same time.
>
> Instead, use FMDatabaseQueue.

Here's the [reference](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabaseQueue.html).

Comment: I have a question when i use  dispatch_queue_t and then the problem none exist. maybe FMDatabaseQueue is the same to handle multi-thread issue. now i want to know the elements in the sqlite table already have lock && unlock in the FMDB source code , so why should we need queue to solve this multi-thread problem ?

Comment: @SevenJustin The database has lock && unlock, not the elements. If you do some update operations, and at same time, you wanna do some delete operations, it maybe occurs errors if you don't put your operations into a queue.

Comment: so i got your meaning, then i will revise my insert or delete method to wrap the [db open]...insert or update....[db close] block with a lock. is it right?

Comment: i use table as a singleSkeleton, and insert update delete methods all have operations with the [db open] and [db close], just like

Comment: @SevenJustin `[db open]`->`delete/update/add`->`[db close]`, and if you do high frequency operations, use `db transactions` and `FMDatabaseQueue `.

Comment: i f I don't want to use FMDatabaseQueue and use lock instead, where should I revise? 

Comment: @SevenJustin You should use `transactions` feature to handle failed operations.

Comment: can you give me any simple example?